# How to deploy many instances of the same Docker image with unique database connection string

Tags: docker

I am researching cloud deployments utilizing Docker containers. Our application will be utilizing Apache Tomcat and a PostgreSQL database.

My question is regarding best practices for configuring and maintaining images for multiple clients when deploying to clusters in the cloud.

We would like to use a single base image for many customers rather than maintaining an image per customer. This means a new context.xml (defines the database connection string for the Tomcat application) for each deployment of the image, as each customer will need to connect to their own database.

I know I can manually copy the context.xml file to the deployed container which is fine until we start to run these containers in a cluster with many replicas. This would require us to copy this connection string to each replica we create and repeat this process every time we update the container with a new version.

Is there a better solution to this problem of many containers running the same image but each group of containers requiring its own database connection string? Or is there a way to leverage container orchestration to update the context.xml file in all of the containers running the same instance at once?

PS. I have looked into using environment variables but the context.xml file is static and will not load values from these variables. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding how Kubernete Pods work. Does a pod consist of all the replicas running on the cluster? If so the kubectl cp command should copy the file to all replicas then correct?

Comment: You should not use `kubectl cp`. When pods crash/die, new pods will get created from the deployment specification and they won't have those files. You should either use environment variables or ConfigMaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you plan to keep track of the database connection strings? They need to reside somewhere...

Services is what allows you to communicate between Pods, and Services are targeting Pods by selector: you can therefore have a Service targeting a cluster of the same Pod type (i.e. your DB)

If you have a DB per customer, you need a Service per customer.
Now the problem is to point each of the App Pods to the right Service.

When you deploy the Pod, you need to know where to point it to. You can pass extra environment variables to your Pod at launch time with the `--env=` flag

You can also add labels to Pods, and if you want to really automate this, you will need some sort of DB or key value store to store to retrieve the 
service name for a Pod, run a script at startup to lookup what is your Pod label and fetch the DB string for it.

Comment: Yes we are planning on having a Service per customer as you mention which will allow us to assign an external IP to each pod. The problem is pointing each pod to the DB. I looked into using environment variables however the context.xml which defines the connection string to the DB does not use environment variables. This is a known limitation of the context files of Tomcat. So I have no way of passing in the correct connection string values at startup. Please correct me if I am mistaken but that is my understanding.

Comment: you can pass ENV VARIABLES to a Pod at startup. They just get added to the environment. That has nothing to do with Tomcat

Comment: This answer is mostly correct. I did end up using environment variables as you suggested. However as I pointed out in my question the Context.xml file used by Tomcat to set the connection string does not seem to use these environment variables. The solution to this problem was to include a shell script inside my docker file, using the CMD option, that would read these environment variables into the context.xml file when starting the container.